# Windows Script to move files older than 30 days with a specific extension to another folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am in need of a script preferably a vbscript for a Windows Server which will archive files in a folder to another folder. Say from `\\folder1\` to `\\folder1\archive\`

The files have the extensions of `.doc` and `.xls`

But also I only want to move files older than 30 days.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), I suppose you are accepting batch file solutions too.
Here you are:

```
pushd \\folder1
forfiles /M *.doc /D -30 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE move @file .\archive\"
forfiles /M *.xls /D -30 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE move @file .\archive\"
popd
```

Due to the syntax you used for the source directory path (`\\folder1\`) I suppose it is given by a UNC path. So I use the `pushd` command which understands such, maps it to a temporary drive it creates and changes the current working directory to the root of that drive.

The `forfiles` command is capable of enumerating a given directory (tree) and iterates through all items that meet a certain mask and modification date (age). Since `forfiles` supports a single mask only, I simply use it twice.

The `popd` command at the end removes that temporary drive which has been created by `pushd`.

For more details about each used command, type it into the command prompt, followed by `/?`.

Comment: Thanks, great.
I adapted it to copy all files:

`pushd \\servername\share\folder1`

`forfiles /M *.* /D -10 /C "cmd /C move @file \\servername\share\folder2\"`

`popd`

`pause`

Answer (score 1):

Below code can do the required.I just added comments here to explain the code here.

```
Option Explicit 
On Error Resume Next 
Dim oFSO, oFolder, sSrcDirectoryPath, sDstDirectoryPath
Dim oFileCollection, oFile, sDir 
Dim iDaysOld 

sSrcDirectoryPath = "C:\folder1" 'Source folder location
sDstDirectoryPath = "C:\folder1\archive" ' archieve folder location
iDaysOld = 30

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sSrcDirectoryPath) 
Set oFileCollection = oFolder.Files 

For each oFile in oFileCollection
    'Change the code here if any other file extension also required to be archieved.
    If (LCase(Right(Cstr(oFile.Name), 3)) = "doc" Or LCase(Right(Cstr(oFile.Name), 3)) = "xls") Then
        If (oFile.DateLastModified < (Date() - iDaysOld)) Then
        oFile.Move(sDstDirectoryPath & "\" & oFile.Name)
        End If 
    End If   
Next 

Set oFSO = Nothing 
Set oFolder = Nothing 
Set oFileCollection = Nothing 
Set oFile = Nothing
```